# Subtract a two-level group mean from every observation in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I need to subtract mean calculated by group from every observation within the group. The challenging part of it is that I have a sub-groupings in the data frame, or two levels: V5 and V4. Here is the example of what my data.frame structure is:

```
B = as.data.frame(matrix(
c(2,2,3,3,4,3,1,5,7,6,4,5,8,9,2,3,8,4,5,0,7,5,6,7,5,3,2,
"A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C",
"TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE"),
nrow=9,ncol=5))
```

so my data.frame `B` looks like this:

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4    V5
1  2  6  5  A  TRUE
2  2  4  0  A  TRUE
3  3  5  7  A  TRUE
4  3  8  5  A  TRUE
5  4  9  6  B FALSE
6  3  2  7  B FALSE
7  1  3  5  C FALSE
8  5  8  3  C FALSE
9  7  4  2  C FALSE
```

So if I average by V5 and V4 I get a new data.frame that I called `test`, which takes into account multilevel grouping:

```
test <- aggregate(. ~ B$V5+B$V4,data=B, mean)
> test
   B$V5 B$V4  V1       V2   V3 V4 V5
1  TRUE    A 2.5 4.500000 3.75  1  2
2 FALSE    B 3.5 4.000000 5.50  2  1
3 FALSE    C 4.0 3.666667 3.00  3  1
```

So what I am struggling with, is to subtract the means of two-level groups in data.frame `test` from original observations in data.frame `B`. Intuitively, I assume there would be an apply() function and some sort of condition statement maybe, however it is a bit advanced coding for me and I am still learning R.

Comment: Hi, in `test` the last two columns are encoded factors: V4 in `B` is A, B or C equal to 1,2 and 3 in `test`. V5 in `B` is TRUE/FALSE, encoded as 1 and 2 in `test`.
I do not need the last two columns in `test`, but I need to subtract numbers in columns V1, V2 and V3 in `test` from the corresponding groups of observations in `B`. It is centring of the data that I want to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(B)`), grouped by "V4", "V5", loop through the subset of data.table (`.SD`) and get the difference of each column with the `mean` of that column for each group

```
library(data.table)
setDT(B)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x- mean(x)), by = .(V4, V5)]
```

---

Or we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
B %>%
  group_by(V4, V5) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(.- mean(.)))
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups: V4, V5 [3]
#          V1    V2         V3     V4     V5
#       <dbl> <dbl>      <dbl> <fctr> <fctr>
#1 -0.5000000  0.25  0.7500000      A   TRUE
#2 -0.5000000 -1.75 -4.2500000      A   TRUE
#3  0.5000000 -0.75  2.7500000      A   TRUE
#4  0.5000000  2.25  0.7500000      A   TRUE
#5  0.5000000  3.50 -0.5000000      B  FALSE
#6 -0.5000000 -3.50  0.5000000      B  FALSE
#7 -3.3333333 -2.00  1.6666667      C  FALSE
#8  0.6666667  3.00 -0.3333333      C  FALSE
#9  2.6666667 -1.00 -1.3333333      C  FALSE
```

assuming that the first 3 columns are `numeric`

#### data

```
B <- structure(list(V1 = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 1, 5, 7), V2 = c(6, 4, 
5, 8, 9, 2, 3, 8, 4), V3 = c(5, 0, 7, 5, 6, 7, 5, 3, 2), V4 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
V5 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("FALSE", 
"TRUE"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", 
"V4", "V5"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi, the code works (don't yet understand what it does), thank you and thanks for explanation of the syntax!

Comment: @marianess  The general format of `data.table` is `dt[i, j, by]` where in `i` we specify the row index - it can be logical, numeric etc to select the rows, `j` to specify the columns, and `by` for grouping variables.  Initially we used `by = list(V4, V5)`, not the `.(...)` can also be used to specify the grouping variables

Answer (score 7):

Here is a solution with base R:

```
B <- data.frame(matrix(c(2,2,3,3,4,3,1,5,7,6,4,5,8,9,2,3,8,4,5,0,7,5,6,7,5,3,2), 9),
  V4=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
  V5=c("TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE","FALSE"))
B[1:3] <- lapply(B[1:3], function(x) x - ave(x, B$V4, B$V5, FUN=mean))
B
```

I used other data. In your example dataframe all columns are factors (you can not calculate with factors, e.g. `mean(...)`).

Comment: thanks! that one is good too, very short! And thanks for comment about my "wrong" data.frame, will keep this mistake in mind!